# Using FastCode and RtlVcl Optimize together

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am using both FastCode and RtlVcl Optimize in my project. Can they conflict? Should I use them together?

---

Delphi 7
http://fastcode.sourceforge.net/
http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25537

Comment: out of curiosity how much difference do they make and what sort of applications benefit?

Comment: yea... I don't really see any use to do that just for a few milliseconds speed improvement(maybe!!) it can also result in unwanted errors or access violations -- very rare cases but still...

Comment: If your code is performing specific tasks they can improve the speed A LOT! Take a look at FastMove for example. Also have you seen how fast Delphi loads when you are using 'Delphi RtlVCL Speed Up'? It can have the same impact on your app.

Comment: @Altar How much difference does it make in your app? I'm genuinely interested. And what aspects of your app do they speed up?

Comment: FastMM and FastCode and RtlVcl Opt (all enabled at the same time) can decrease the run time of my app from 2.2 sec to 2.0 sec.

Comment: @Altar Is that run time or startup time?

Comment: @Altar If it is startup time then I'd class that as within the bounds of measurement tolerance.

Comment: @Altar run time measured after startup has completed? Normally when benchmarking you want something longer than 2s because such a short run time makes timing results less reliable.

Comment: Yes. I am not using the standard Windows timer to measure the time. The process was also set to high priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use them both (in d2010) with no problems

Comment: I thought Embarcadero absorbed the FastCode stuff into the Delphi source long before D2010. Certainly my copy of the Delphi RTL source suggests so.

Comment: @Altar Yes you said that already, but André talks about D2010.

Comment: "I thought Embarcadero absorbed the FastCode" - I don't know that. I have Delphi 7

Comment: @Altar the "absorption" was after D7.